# Can't Add Answer to Questions from Android App

Tags: bug, android-app

The "Add an Answer" button is not visible in this [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/8904/18161) in the android app. The question can be answered from the website from Nexus 10 in which I am running the SE app.

I am running Android 5.0.1 an SE Android App v 1.0.54. I am linking a screen shot. I think this is a bug. Maybe because there are already 11 long answers?

[image]